# Shortcut in dual boot (windows+ubuntu) issues

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, mount, shortcuts

I have ubuntu + windows (dual boot) installed, in their own seperate disk partitions but in same hard disk. So my files are in the windows partition, while I prefer booting to ubuntu, so I created links to my files and put them in the linux desktop.

**Problem:**

When I boot ubuntu, the shortcuts don't work (are dead links) because the windows partition is not mounted. If I mount it by visiting it with nautilus and then log out and log in again, the links work perfectly.

**Question:**

How can I fix this problem? How to tell ubuntu to mount the windows partition before logging in?